# Pushing out MSI files

Tags: deployment, installation, windows-installer

I have a product which has been traditionally shipped as an MSI file.  It is deployed through some sort of SMS push to thousands of desktops by our various clients.  The software we use to create these installers is getting long in the tooth and we are looking to replace it.  We have already standardized on InstallAnywhere for most of our products as we support many operating systems.  Unfortunately InstallAnywhere cannot produce MSI files.

I am wondering if it is required that SMS use MSI files or if it can handle other installer types (.exe).  If not, are there any open source programmes for creating MSI files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your clients are using SMS then you're in the clear... SMS supports EXE. You enter a command line when creating 'Programs' and clients are probably already calling msiexec to launch the MSI. Also I'm pretty sure SMS predates the MSI file format :)

However if they're using `Active Directory / Group Policy Objects`.. then you're SOL as that does depend on MSI format for deployment.

If you do want to stick with InstallAnywhere, there are a number of "MSI repackaging" tools available. Assuming you're looking at a basic application (device drivers might be an issue) then repackaging should be a fairly painless process.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create `MSI` files, try [WiX: Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

It's an addon to Visual Studio 2005 and 2008, is open-source, and Microsoft developed.  You can use XML to specify and create MSI files.  There is a [wealth](http://robmensching.com/blog/) [of](http://www.joyofsetup.com/) [resources](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/) available on it, and `WiX 3.0` is, although in beta, is very complete.

Also, note that you don't have to start from scratch, you can decompile an existing MSI using the WiX `Dark` utility, modify the XML in any way you like, and then recompile it into an MSI.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with group policies, there's the `ZAP` file alternative, but I would recommend regardless that you learn `MSI`. It's not that hard, and very flexible.